# Is it possible, with a discord.js bot to know on which device is connected a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I want to know if it's possible to get on which device a member is using discord (Web, Desktop, Mobile App) to put it in a userinfo command.

Thx for the advice.

Comment: It's not possible at the moment.

Comment: Either if it was possible you would need to make a lot of ``API Requests``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you can, using a guild's presences. Make sure to [read the docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence?scrollTo=clientStatus).

Comment: Yea actually I didn't know for that but thanks to Tenclea you can use ``.clientStatus``

Comment: Be aware that offline users (which is a status that can be chosen deliberately) have no presence. https://github.com/discordjs/discord.js/issues/7837

Answer (score 1):

yes it is

client.on("message", async message => {
if (message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith('-device')){

const user = message.mentions.users.first();

```
let devices = [];

if (!user) {
  var status = message.author.presence.clientStatus;
} else {
  var status = user.presence.clientStatus;

  if (user.bot) {
    const webbot = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${user.tag} device:`)
    .setDescription("web")

    message.channel.send(webbot)

    return;
  };
};

if (!status) {
  // status is unavailable
  const nostatus = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`${user.tag} device:`)
    .setDescription("unavaliable")

    message.channel.send(nostatus)

  return;
};

if (status.desktop) {
    devices.push('desktop');
};

if (status.web) {
    devices.push('web');
};

if (status.mobile) {
    devices.push('mobile');
};

devices = devices.join(', ') || 'None';

const dev = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle(`${user.tag} device:`)
.setDescription(devices)

message.channel.send(dev)

// send message
```

}
})

Answer (score 0):

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
let member = message.mentions.members.first();

function getDevice(GuildMember = Discord.GuildMember.prototype) {
let userS = GuildMember.presence.clientStatus;
if (userS) {
    if (GuildMember.user.bot) {
         return "Web";
    } else if (userS.desktop) {
        return "Computer";
    } else if (userS.mobile) {
        return "Mobile";
    } else if (userS.web) {
        return "Web";
    } else { return "unknown"; }
  } else { return "unknown" };
} console.log(`User device is ${getDevice(member)}`);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. 
Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please edit your answer and explain 
how it answers the specific question being asked. See [How to Answer]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30618725)